# How to replace only certain part of the text in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, string-matching, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace a certain words in the text. But don't want the word to be replaced if it's a part of a url. For example: the word technical. It replaced in both the places(including url).

```
select regexp_replace('Part of the Technical Network Group https://technical.com/sites/',
                      'technical','tech',1,0,'i')
  from dual
```

Output:

```
Part of the tech Network Group https://tech.com/sites/
```

Expected Output:

```
Part of the tech Network Group https://technical.com/sites/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in 2 steps.

First, if word be present in between words, second if the word is first word of sentence.

```
select 
      regexp_replace(regexp_replace('technical Part of Technical Group https://technical.com/sites/',
                     ' technical', 
                     ' tech',1,0,'i'), 'technical ', 'tech ',1,0,'i') 
  from dual
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: How about if we had the word at the beginning of the text? It doesn't replace that as there is no space preceding to it.

Comment: Here is your answer. I temporarily changed the word to ***, and then witched it back to what it was. See answer above.

Comment: This works. Thank you. Instead of replace, can we identify the word technical in the url if present using SUBSTR?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. It would create unnecessary hectic. What if the technical  is not present at the position you mentioned in `SUBSTR` ? It will change something you don't want to change.

Comment: Let me reframe. How can we identify the term technical when its a part of the URL? Say we have to check that in the WHERE clause.

Comment: `select regexp_instr('Part of Technical Group https://technical.com/sites/',
                      '//technical', 1)from dual` If this returns 0, then word is not present in URL, If it returns natural number, then its is present. Or you can use `case` with `like` to check for pattern existence.

Comment: the above query gives `Part of tech Group https:technical.com/sites/` as result ( *i.e..without slashes after https* )

Comment: `select regexp_instr('Part of Technical Group https:technical.com/sites/', '//technical', 1)from dual` This is giving 0 on my side. Is this what you executed ? @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: I just mentioned about your answer. Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30b62c1e7939d5363c2f5e7f8793693c)

Comment: That was a catch. Thanks for pointing it out @BarbarosÖzhan. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ArifSherKhan now it's OK. Btw, you even don't need duplication of `regexp_replace()`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan we need 2. What if technical is first word of string ? See [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3abc6ed8b73996d567245a9f9cf3e527)

Answer (score 0):

This method uses one regexp_replace() call. It matches the word 'technical' (case-insensitive) only when it is preceded by the start of the line or a space, and saves that preceding character. It gets replaced with the saved character (referenced by `'\1'`) followed by 'tech'.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'Technical Part of the Technical Network Group https://technical.com/sites/' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(str, '(^| )technical', '\1tech', 1, 0, 'i') fixed
from tbl;

FIXED                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------
tech Part of the tech Network Group https://technical.com/sites/
```